# Login with Paypal button integration as per new API change

Tags: paypal

Paypal has recently sent an email saying to update the integration for login with paypal button.  Deadline is 4th April 2019
What should be the URL for this login with paypal button.

**i.e.** - with what I should replace

```
api.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/auth/protocol/openidconnect/v1/authorize
```

What should be correct URL as per new Integration.